# i3status script that change its text by itself

Tags: shell-script, i3

I am trying to add a block for rss the latest news in my status bar.

The news is composed by a title and a description. The full text doesn't fit in the status bar, so I would like to make it read display part of the text incrementally.

I have tried to delay multiple echos, but it doesn't work. It is surely because the output of the script should be only one line.

A solution would be to make a script that display a different line of the news after each call, that I could use the interval of the status bar to call the script several times.

How can I make such a script ?
I am also opened to other solutions.

Thank you